# [ CAKEPHP ]Question in generate Xml file within controller snippet

Tags: xml, cakephp

I need to generate xml file from controller 
after I find in google  and found [solution](http://www.ninjacodermonkey.co.uk/2010/11/cakephp-array-to-xml-from-within-controller/)
but I have question in snippet 
1.how to access file in webroot for example in snippet

```
$xmlFile = fopen('/webroot/xml/xml.xml', 'a');
```

thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xmlFile = fopen(WWW_ROOT . 'xml/xml.xml', 'a');`